# File name from StreamReader C# - asp.net MVC3 to array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, arrays, json

my application is MVC3 C#; I am populating two dropdownlists using json using the following:

```
public ActionResult CheckWord(string cword)
    {
        try
        {
            List<string[]> arrayList = new List<string[]>();
            List<string[]> stateList = new List<string[]>();
            //
            List<string[]> fileList = new List<string[]>();
            //
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Video"), "*.srt");
            string[] fnList = new string[filePaths.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < fnList.Length; ++i)
            {
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePaths[i]);
                fnList[i] = fi.Name.Substring(0, fi.Name.LastIndexOf(".srt"));

            }
            int nFiles = filePaths.Length;
            string cacheline = "";
            string line;

            for (int i = 0; i < nFiles; ++i)
            {
                StreamReader file = new StreamReader(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Video/" + fnList[i] + ".srt"));

                List<string> lines = new List<string>();
                List<string> statments = new List<string>();
                //
                List<string> fnames = new List<string>();
                //
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains(cword))
                    {
                        statments.Add(line);
                   //     fnames.Add(file);
                        lines.Add(cacheline);
                    }
                    cacheline = line;
                }
                file.Close();
                var array = lines.ToArray();
                arrayList.Add(array);
                stateList.Add(statments.ToArray());
            }

            return Json(new { success = true, fnList = fnList, arrayList = arrayList.ToArray(), stateList = stateList.ToArray() });
        }
        catch { }
        return Json(new { success = false });
    }
```

I am checking if a word exists in a group of files; then display the names of files in one dropdownlist and the lines from each file in the other dropdownlist.  It works fine, however it gives me a list of all files becasue I am sending back fnlist.  However I am trying to display only the files that contain that word; I could not get the file name from the StreamReader and add it to an array fileList.  I would appreciate your suggestions, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you are looking for but since you are creating StreamReader from a file name why not have file name in a separate variable and use it later:

```
var fileName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(
    "/Video/" + fnList[i] + ".srt");
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(fileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Already so many lists! Why not another? You already open the file with `fnList[i]` within the context of the loop, so...

```
List<string[]> results = new List<string[]>();
....
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) {
  if (line.Contains(cword)) {
    results.Add(fnList[i]);
    break; // optional, if possible, but if you need to continue check for dupes
  }
}
....
return Json(new { 
  success = true, 
  fnList = results.ToArray(),
  arrayList = arrayList.ToArray(), 
  stateList = stateList.ToArray() 
});
```

Comment: Thanks Grant, since I am not that experienced; how can I add the arrayList and stateList as per your answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("setup.txt");

Later on, we would like to print the name of the file being used by stream reader.
eg, if there is an error, I would like a message box that displays "error reading file: 'filename'"

```
 MessageBox.Show("Error loading " + ((FileStream)file.BaseStream).Name);
```